# Error showing to read CSV file for mapreduce program in java

Tags: java, csv, mapreduce, bigdata

Below code is `Mapper` class in `mapreduce`. What I am trying to code is to read `CSV` file and store two columns data in each line ( column 1 which means `userId` and column 6 which shows `CheckOutDateTime` for book) into `HashMap`. I think my code for function of `getMapFromCSV` in `StubMapper` class seems wrong. Could someone enlighten me? At the bottom, I put the output for error. Thank you all for your any help and suggestion.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;



public class StubMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, MinMaxCountTuple> {

    private Text outUserId = new Text();
    private MinMaxCountTuple outTuple = new MinMaxCountTuple();

    private final static SimpleDateFormat frmt = 
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM--dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    public static HashMap<String, String> getMapFromCSV(String filePath) throws IOException
    {

        HashMap<String, String> words = new HashMap<String, String>();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        //= in.readLine())
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String columns[] = line.split("\t");
            if (!words.containsKey(columns[1])) {
                words.put(columns[1], columns[6]);
            }

        }
        //in.close();

        return words;



    }

@Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {


      HashMap<String, String> parsed = getMapFromCSV(value.toString());
      //String columns[] = value.toString().split("\t");

      String strDate = parsed.get("CheckoutDateTime");

      //String userId = columns[1];
      //String strDate = columns[6];
      String userId = parsed.get("BibNumber");

      try {
        Date creationDate = frmt.parse(strDate);

        outTuple.setMin(creationDate);
        outTuple.setMax(creationDate);

        outTuple.setCount(1);

        outUserId.set(userId);

        context.write(outUserId, outTuple);

      } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
}
```

And showing follow error which I am not being able to figure it out. I think problem seems to happen in `getMapFromCSV` function which is in `StubMapper` class.
The parameter of that function will has information of `CSV` attributes. What I am trying to store into `HashMap` is key and value as a pair. But, I have no idea how I can change. Please specify if you have an idea how I can fix it.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Code,Description,Code Type,Format Group,Format Subgroup,Category Group,Category Subgroup (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at StubMapper.getMapFromCSV(StubMapper.java:27)
    at StubMapper.map(StubMapper.java:50)
    at StubMapper.map(StubMapper.java:14)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:673)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Comment: Added detail around the issue on the code. please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing important concept in `mapreduce`. The problem is with the below line

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

// Below is the problematic line
      HashMap<String, String> parsed = getMapFromCSV(value.toString());
```

Perhaps you are assuming that the `Text value` is the `CSV filename` and hence trying to get the value from the file.

It does not work like that. The `Text value` input to mapper is one line from the CSV file.

Assuming, your CSV is in below structure:

```
Code,Description,Code Type,Format Group,Format Subgroup,Category Group,Category Subgroup
111,sample description,codeType1,IN,....
```

Your code should be something like

```
@Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  if(value.toString().startWith("Code,Description")){
      // Skip header line (first line) of CSV
       return;
  }

  String data[] = value.toString().split(",", -1);

  String code= data[0];
  String codeType = data[2];

....
....
and so one
```

Answer (score 0):

The error appears in this line:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
```

1. Check the value of `filePath`
2. Check if a file is located at `filePath`
3. Check if content of the file is valid

Comment: Thanks but I already know that information the problem is that it is not correct syntax for getting information from csv about my code.